# creating cutscenes using OOP and pygame

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I'm probably missing something obvious or simple, but i'm struggling to add an 'if self.cut_scene_manager.cut_scene is None:' into my input of my player class

Here is my main.py and player.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
from settings import *
from level import Level
from player import Player
from npc import NPC
from cut_scenes import CutSceneManager, CutSceneOne

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Passerine')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.level = Level()
        self.npc_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.player = Player((640, 360), self.level.all_sprites, self.level)
        self.npc1 = NPC((1460, 530),self.level.all_sprites, self.level)

        self.cut_scene_manager = CutSceneManager(self.screen)
        

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            dt = self.clock.tick() / 1000
            self.npc_group.update(dt)
            self.npc_group.draw(self.screen)
            self.level.run(dt)
            self.cut_scene_manager.update()
            self.cut_scene_manager.draw()
            self.player.update(self.cut_scene_manager)
            pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()





import pygame
from settings import *
from support import *
from cut_scenes import *

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, group, level):
        super().__init__(group)

        self.import_assets()
        self.status = 'down_idle'
        self.frame_index = 0

        #general setup
        self.image = self.animations[self.status][self.frame_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
        self.hitbox = self.rect.copy().inflate((-126, -70))
        self.z = LAYERS['main']

        #movement attribtes
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center)
        self.speed = 200
        self.level = level
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

        # spawn point
        self.spawn_point = 30,440

        self.cut_scene_manager = CutSceneManager(self.screen)

        # Set initial position to spawn point
        self.reset_position()
    
    def import_assets(self):
        self.animations = {'up': [], 'down':[], 'left':[], 'right':[],
                           'right_idle':[], 'left_idle':[], 'up_idle':[], 'down_idle':[]}
        
        for animation in self.animations.keys():
            full_path = 'graphics/character/' + animation
            self.animations[animation] = import_folder(full_path)

    def reset_position(self):
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.spawn_point)
        self.hitbox.center = self.pos
        self.rect.center = self.hitbox.center

    def set_spawn_point(self, new_spawn_point):
        self.spawn_point = new_spawn_point

    def animate(self, dt):
        self.frame_index += 4 * dt
        if self.frame_index >= len(self.animations[self.status]):
            self.frame_index = 0

        self.image = self.animations[self.status][int(self.frame_index)]

    
    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.cut_scene_manager.cut_scene is None:

            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.direction.y = -1
                self.status = 'up'
            elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.direction.y = 1
                self.status = 'down'
            else:
                self.direction.y = 0

            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.direction.x = 1
                self.status = 'right'
            elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.direction.x = -1
                self.status = 'left'
            else:
                self.direction.x = 0

    def get_status(self): #checks if player should be idle
        if self.direction.magnitude() == 0:
            self.status = self.status.split('_')[0] + '_idle'

    def check_collision(self, new_pos):
        # Create a rect for the new position
        player_rect = pygame.Rect(new_pos[0] - self.rect.width / 2, new_pos[1] - self.rect.height / 2, self.rect.width, self.rect.height)

        # Iterate over the sprites in the 'Ground/walls' layer
        for sprite in self.level.all_sprites:
            if sprite.z == LAYERS['Walls'] and sprite.rect.colliderect(player_rect):
                    #print("collision with wall")
                    return True  # Collision detected

        return False  # No collision

    def move(self,dt):
     # normalizing a vector
        if self.direction.magnitude() > 0:
            self.direction = self.direction.normalize()

        # vertical movement
        new_y = self.pos.y + self.direction.y * self.speed * dt

        # Check if the new y position is within bounds
        if 430 <= new_y <= 675:  # Replace MIN_Y_AXIS and MAX_Y_AXIS with your desired y-axis bounds
            self.pos.y = new_y
            self.hitbox.centery = round(self.pos.y)
            self.rect.centery = self.hitbox.centery

        # horizontal movement
        self.pos.x += self.direction.x * self.speed * dt
        self.hitbox.centerx = round(self.pos.x)
        self.rect.centerx = self.hitbox.centerx

        # Update hitbox and rect
        self.hitbox.center = self.pos
        self.rect.center = self.hitbox.center

    def update(self, dt):
        self.input()
        self.get_status()
        self.move(dt)
        self.animate(dt)

        if self.rect.centerx > 800:
            self.cut_scene_manager.start_cut_scene(CutSceneOne(self))
```

I've tried defining cut_scene_manager within the Player class, but more problems keep occurring, usually with Player lacking attributes, or with CutSceneManager having 'unsupported opperand types'. Apologies if the problem is very obvious, I'm fairly new to Pygame and OOP, but this is a school project. Thank you!

Comment: What is a `CutSceneManager`? Is that from a package you downloaded separately from `pygame`?